# Cannot update Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

I simply click *Help -> Check for Updates* and go through the wizard and I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.browser,3.6.4.201503050855-RELEASE
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted,3.6.4.201503050855-RELEASE
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.quicksearch,3.6.4.201503050855-RELEASE
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.ui,3.6.4.201503050855-RELEASE
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.aspectj.runtime.source,1.7.0.20120703164200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.core.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.ui.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.core,0.9.0.201401250701
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.javafx,2.2.0.201401250701
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.osgi,0.9.0.201401250701
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util,0.9.0.201401250701
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.net4j.jms.api,3.0.0.v20110215-1551
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.quicksearch.feature,3.6.4.201503050855-RELEASE
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard,3.6.4.201503050855-RELEASE
```

I am trying to update because my Scala plug-in does not have worksheets and I just seen I have a lot of updates I need to take care of.

If trying download the Scala plug-in I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.aspectj.runtime.source,1.7.0.20120703164200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.core.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.ui.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Next steps solved my problem:

1. Review and delete excess old repositories.  *`Help > Install New Software > Available Software Sites`* and deselect all Update Sites for older Eclipse versions. I had two Spring repositories for 4.3 and 4.4 version.
2. Clear `<eclipse folder>/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache` directory.
3. Check for updates again.

Source: [Update Error [Mac]](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/14#issuecomment-78294565)

Comment: after try a lot of solution found this one helpful. the issue was with the `SpringSource Update Site for Eclipse` where both `4.3` and `4.4` are enabled. so I just disabled the `4.3` and also deleted `<eclipse folder>/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache`.